# How do you configure Django to send mail through Postfix?

Tags: python, django, email, postfix-mta

How do you configure Django and Postfix to send emails for Django apps?

I am able to do it using Gmail server settings but I want to send email from my own server using my own domain.

Comment: If django can be configured to use an SMTP server, you could probably just install postfix and point django to localhost:25.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean putting this in settings.py EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Assuming that postfix is setup correctly, I think that should work. I am not familiar with django, but judging by [their documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_PORT), those are the right settings.

Comment: I did that already. Didn't work.

Comment: Debug the postfix mail server first. Try typing `telnet localhost 25` on the machine to see if you get a response. If you get a response that looks like `220 hostname.local ESMTP Postfix` then it's on. Type quit, and check the mail queue by typing `mailq`. This will show you if your messages aren't being delivered. The reasoning will be in the maillog, usually `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: @weberwithoneb When i did telnet localhost 587 it gave:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62945/discussion-between-monique-and-weberwithoneb).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I banged my head a lot before realizing that it is actually quite simple:

add this to your **settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Whatever <whatever@example.com>'
```

Also make sure that a fully qualified domain name (say mybox.example.com) is set up on your server ([how](https://serverfault.com/a/490826/58595)),

Then you need to have these lines in your **/etc/postfix/main.cf**:

```
myhostname = mybox.example.com
mydestination = localhost.server.com, localhost, example.com
```

Also you have to set up proper MX record for your domain (check [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/)) in your dns server (and in your registrar, if you handle dns lookup through you them)